# З Паскаля на пайтон

Tags: python, pascal

Есть код на паскале:

```
var i, j : integer;
BEGIN
  readln(i, j);
  if i=j then
    if i=12 then
      writeln('12')
    else
      writeln('0')
  else
    writeln(i+j-1)
END
```

Можно на пайтон?

Comment: Можно. . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

можно

```
readln(i, j)
```

заменить на

```
i, j = map(int, input().split())
```

а

```
writeln
```

заменить на

```
print
```

остальное все более-менее такое же только в соответствии с питоновскими правилами